# Chinese delete problem when golang bufio.NewScanner scan interacts

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    fmt.Print(scanner.Text())
}
```

```bash
# enter two Chinese characters, and press the delete key once
> go run .
中文
中�%
```

When running this code in the terminal, it prompts the user for input. If the user enters Chinese characters, there may be issues with deleting characters, such as requiring two deletions to remove one character (likely because only one byte is being deleted at a time).

I have attempted to modify the terminal's encoding to both UTF8 and GBK, but neither have been effective.

Comment: Can you show an example of the problem?

Comment: I have improved the question and provided corresponding examples.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your terminal, rather than with go. For testing purposes: can you run `cat` (which will just wait for you to type things on stdin, and will repeat it on stdout when you hit `[Enter]`) and check if you have the same issue ?

Comment: You are correct, but I have also set my encoding to the correct type. Why am I still experiencing this issue and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Indeed this seems to be a terminal problem, not a Go problem. The Scanner does not receive the characters at all until you hit enter, so you can't fix the delete issue by changing the Go code. It will be more appropriate to re-tag your question with what terminal you are using, and add more detail about that.